# Open and Closed Sets Over Alexandroff Space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to proof this theorem. I already proved 1 and 2 but I'm struggling to prove 3.

Theorem 7

1. For any two different elements $P$ and $Q$ of an Alexandroff space is
   $$
   \begin{array}{l}
   P \in O Q \quad \Longrightarrow \quad Q \notin O P \quad \text { and } \\
   P \in C Q \quad \Longrightarrow Q \notin C P .
   \end{array}
   $$
2. $P \in C Q \quad \Longleftrightarrow Q \in O P$.
3. $C P \subseteq C Q \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad O Q \subseteq O P$

Where $OQ$ is the maximal neighbourhood of $Q$ and $OP$ the maximal neighbourhood of $P$ and $CP$ is the smallest closed set containing $P$. The same for $CQ$ respectively.

My attempt:

Suppose that $C P \subseteq C Q$. As both are the intersection of the closed sets that contain $P$ and $Q$ respectively, then both $P$ and $Q$ are in $CQ$. By 1, we know that if $P \in CQ$ then $Q \notin C P$. That is, $Q \in X - CP$, which is an open set that contains $Q$ but do not contain $P$. Because of that, $P \notin OQ$.

That is what I thought it will be useful, but I can't find a way to get to the conclusion. Thanks for reading. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: For any $Q\in X$, the maximal nbhd of $Q$ is $X$ itself, contradicting (1); are you sure that $OQ$ isn’t the **minimal** nbhd of $Q$? (1) is still false unless the Alexandroff space is $T_0$. \\ To continue your attempt, let $U$ be any open nbhd of $P$; $P\in CQ=\operatorname{cl}\{Q\}$, so $Q\in U$. Thus, $Q$ is in every open nbhd of $P$; $X$ is Alexandroff, so the intersection of those nbhds of $P$ is the minimal nbhd of $P$, and $Q$ is in it, so the minimal nbhd of $Q$ is contained in the minimal nbhd of $P$.

Comment: $OP$ is the **minimal** neighbourhood of $P$. It exists as $X$ is Alexandroff. You also assume ( as is common) that $X$ is $T_0$ so that a topological space exactly  corresponds to a partial order: $P \le Q$ iff $P \in CQ$ and the antisymmetry of $\le$ coresponds to the $T_0$ property in $X$. Etc.

Comment: Otherwise put: you assume $P \to OP$ is an injection from $X$ into its topology. The Sam holds for $P \to CP$ from the space into its closed sets. This is then also an order isomorphism from the aforementioned $\le$ into the closed sets with inclusion partial order.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for your response. I just don't understand why $CQ = cl\{Q\}$, and how that implies that $Q \in U$.

Comment: $CQ$ is the smallest closed set containing $Q$ so it equals almost by definition the closure of $\{Q\}$. Your text likes it’s own weird notations for some reason.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks, that's the way it is explained in the text. I find it really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that $T_0$ is part of your definition of Alexandroff space.

So $P \neq Q$ implies that there is an open set $O$ that contains only one of $\{P,Q\}$. So suppose $P \in OQ$ and we want to show $Q \notin OP$. If (to get a contradiction) $Q \in OP$, then $OQ \subseteq OP$ and $OQ$ is a subset of $O$ that contains *both* $P$ and $Q$ and this contradicts how $O$ was chosen.

This shows the first implication of 1. OTOH suppose $P \in CQ$ then $OP$ intersects $\{Q\}$ or $Q \in OP$ so by the first implication $P \notin OQ$, so $P \in OQ^\complement$ and the latter is closed so $CP \subseteq OQ^\complement \ni Q$ which implies $Q \notin CP$. This shows the second implication.

As to 2: $P \in CQ$ iff every open neighbourhood of $P$ intersects $\{Q\}$ iff $OP$ intersects $\{Q\}$ iff $Q \in OP$. QED, just definitions.

Suppose $CP \subseteq CQ$. $OP$ is open and contains $P$ and $P \in CQ$ by the previous inclusion. So $Q \in OP$ so by minimality $OQ \subseteq OP$.

The reverse implication is also easy: if $OQ \subseteq OP$, then $Q \in OP$ and $2$ gives $P \in CQ$ and hence $CP \subseteq CQ$ by minimaility of $CP$ again.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and prove the entire theorem, it helped me a lot. I just get a little confused with the notion of minimality. Thank you. :)